# browser back/forward button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask a question about the back and forward button.
I have this jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function($) {
   if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {  
       window.history.pushState("forward", null, "./index.html");
       $(window).on("popstate", function() {
           that.handleBack();    
       });
    }
});
```

This code has effent for the back and the forward button too.
How could I write confition for the buttons?
So I would like to make similar code like this:

```
If (back button){
 handleBack();
}

Else if(forward button){
 delete history or disabble the forward button.
}
```

Could you help me, how could I make this solution?
Thanks your help in advance.

Comment: What exactly does your jQuery code does? It seems incomplete. `that.handleBack();` is not defined, for example.

Comment: Yes, thats true, I just wrote it.

Comment: My problem with this code, that $(window).on("popstate", function() works for the back and forward button too, and I want to handle separately.